# WPF C# How to bind and set a List in custom model class in WPF with x:array

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having a problem with my first forays into WPF territory, trying to populate a list in a custom model class from XAML.

The exception I'm getting is:

> Additional information: 'Set property 'Project.Model.GanttModel.Tasks'
>   threw an exception.' Line number '19' and line position '27'.

This is the Model:GanttModel... line.

*My question is how to populate the elements of the "GanttModelTest" model's "TasksTest" list?*

**My model class:**

```
    public class GanttModel : DependencyObject {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TasksProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Tasks", typeof(ObservableCollection<Task>), typeof(GanttModel));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChartDateRangeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ChartDateRange", typeof(DateTimeRange), typeof(GanttModel));

    public DateTimeRange ChartDateRange {
        get {
            return GetValue(ChartDateRangeProperty) as DateTimeRange;
        }

        set {
            SetValue(ChartDateRangeProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Task> Tasks {
        get {
            return GetValue(TasksProperty) as ObservableCollection<Task>;
        }

        set {
            SetValue(TasksProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public GanttModel() {
        this.Tasks = new ObservableCollection<Task>();
    }
}
```

**The relevant parts of my XAML:**

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="TasksTest" Type="Model:Task">
        <Model:Task Name="Task 1" Start="07-20-2013" Finish="08-01-2013" />
        <Model:Task Name="Task 2" Start="07-19-2013" Finish="07-31-2013" />
        <Model:Task Name="Task 3" Start="07-18-2013" Finish="07-30-2013" />
        <Model:Task Name="Task 4" Start="07-17-2013" Finish="07-29-2013" />
        <Model:Task Name="Task 5" Start="07-16-2013" Finish="07-28-2013" />
    </x:Array>

    <Model:GanttModel x:Key="GanttModelTest"
                      ChartDateRange="07-01-2013,08-01-2013"
                      Tasks="{StaticResource TasksTest}" />

    etc...etc...etc...

    <ListBox x:Name="GanttTasks"
             ItemsSource="{StaticResource GanttModelTest}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TaskTemplate}"/>

    </UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TasksProperty` type is `ObservableCollection<Task>` but you try to assign an `Task[]`  to it. Because there is no implicit convention between the two type that is why the Set  throws the exception.

You have two options:

Change your `TasksProperty` to use `Task[]` instead of `ObservableCollection<Task>`.

Or build an `ObservableCollection<Task>` in XAML, but because you cannot use XAML2009 features in WPF so cannot directly create an ObservableCollection in WPF XAML. See also the documenation: [Notes on XAML Usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

What you can do is to derive from `ObservableCollection`

```
public class TaskCollection : ObservableCollection<Task> { }
```

And now you can use this non generic version in XAML:

```
<Model:TaskCollection x:Key="TasksTest">
        <Model:Task Name="Task 1" Start="07-20-2013" Finish="08-01-2013" />
        <Model:Task Name="Task 2" Start="07-19-2013" Finish="07-31-2013" />
        <Model:Task Name="Task 3" Start="07-18-2013" Finish="07-30-2013" />
        <Model:Task Name="Task 4" Start="07-17-2013" Finish="07-29-2013" />
        <Model:Task Name="Task 5" Start="07-16-2013" Finish="07-28-2013" />
</Model:TaskCollection>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, though this results in the following exception: `error MC3074: The tag 'ObservableCollection' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=System'. Line 11 Position 10.`

Comment: Which .net version are you using? Because the localication of the `ObservableCollection` changed. If you are using .net 3.5 you need `xmlns:coll="clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=WindowsBase"`

Comment: Tried it with WindowsBase, just now, no luck there either.I'm using 4.0

Comment: Ok, I'm tend to forget that the XAML 2009 cannot be used in WPF, so the generic support is quite limited, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Okay I did as you said, but now there's a new error: `'Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.ItemsSource' threw an exception.' Line number '63' and line position '18'.` This is on the line with `<ListBox x:Name="GanttTasks"
                 ItemsSource="{StaticResource GanttModelTest}"
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TaskTemplate}"/>`. Is it really this complicated to synchronize a simple collection of items in WPF?...

Comment: After some careful thought & backtracking, I've found that what I messed up was the ItemsSource property that had been pointing to GanttModelTest instead of TasksTest. Again, thanks for the explanation!